# Is it possible to create a table and then to select from it in one query?

Tags: mysql

I'm curious if there's a way to do a select on a table which is, itself the product of a select.  Something (pseudo) along the lines of

```
    select a,b,c from 
(select id as a, name as b, phone as c, date as d from some_table) 
where  d = now();
```

So, in effect the parenthetical would return a table, whose columns are defined by the `as` and then the outer `select` could go and query that result.

If not exactly this, I'd be curious to know what vaguely analogous approach I could use.

The reason I need this is that I have a fairly extensive pivot query that I run on my user data, and I would love to be able to select from the fairly massive result.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: well... this *exact syntax is just wrong, and the various other stabs at it didn't work, so, I'm wondering what the right approach is, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Define "just wrong". All I can see is that the `d` column is unknown and should be inside the parentheses.

Comment: create a view in your first query and then select from that view?

Comment: right, so... I need that d column to be visible to the outer select, just as it would be if rather than `(select stuff)` there was an actual table name there.  That's the crux of my question.

Comment: @HanutSingh, I'm not familiar with Views.  Could you recommend a tutorial? Or should I try to just parse the official mySQL docs? (they're generally better for reference, to look up stuff you already know, than to try to actually learn something, in my experience)

Comment: Your statement basically works, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05fd6/2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that's incredibly annoying... I believe I tried EXACTLY this and was met with a syntax error... I guess I must have done something slightly differently.  Please post that as an answer, I'll select is as correct. (and thanks very much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably got an error that says something like "derived table needs an alias"

The following works:

```
select a,b,c 
from (
     select id as a, 
            name as b, 
            phone as c, 
            some_date as d 
     from some_table
) as t 
where  d <= now();
```

The alias `t` defines a so called derived table.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05fd6/2

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Try this:

```
select A.a,A.b,A.c from 
(select id as a, name as b, phone as c, date as d from some_table where  d = now()) A
```

It is called a derived table.

To move the `WHERE` outside the subquery:

```
select A.a,A.b,A.c, A.d from 
(select id as a, name as b, phone as c, date as d from some_table) A
where A.d = now()
```

Comment: No, it's called a "*derived table*".

Comment: on what part of the query that creates a table?

Comment: this looks very promising... is there a way to move the where out to the outer select? I realize *this example doesn't have any obvious reason for doing so, but in my real world query, I really do need to cull the result down based on some criteria.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I updated my answer with the `d` outside the derived table.